# How to set a member variable from outside of class and make use of that varible inside class in C++ ?

Tags: c++, ios7, cocos2d-x

I am pretty much new to cocos2dx and c++ as well. I am having problems in passing data between classes.

Here is My problem

I have a class1, in which i need to set value of a variable and call a function of an another class let's say "Class2".

I need to do this in class1 without making an object of class2.

What i did so far is like the following.

**Class1.cpp**

```
#include "class2.h"
void Class1::methodinClassOne()
{
  class2::imageName = this->str;
  class2::doSth();
}
```

**class2.h**

```
class class2 {

public:
    std::string imageName;
    static void doSth();
};
```

**class2.mm**

```
#include "class2.h"
using namespace cocos2d;

void class2::doSth() {

id sth = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];

if ([sth isKindOfClass:[AppController class]])
{

    printf("class2::doSth imageName %s",imageName.c_str());

    SpriteVC *SPVC = [[SpriteVC alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];

    SPVC.imageNameString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%s",imageName.c_str()];

    NSLog(@"class2::doSth imageName == %@",[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%s",imageName.c_str()]);

    SPVC.imageView.frame = CGRectMake(480, 320, 333, 333);

    AppController *controller = (AppController *)sth;

    [controller.viewController.view addSubview:SPVC.imageView];
}
}
```

**The Error Is like the Following**

[image]

inside class2.h
I also tried using

```
static std::string imageName;
```

instead of

```
std::string imageName;
```

But then it gives me the following error

```
Undefined symbols for architecture i386:"class2::imageName", referenced from:class2::doSth() in XBridge.o
```

I know i am missing a very basic concept of C++ here. but couldn't seems to find whats wrong.
Please help me out here.
thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In addition to their declaration, static member variables have to be defined outside of the class body.
So first, you have to declare your member variable `imageName` as static in the `class2` header file, and then you also have to define the variable in the corresponding mm file:

**class2.h**

```
class class2 {

public:
    static std::string imageName;
    static void doSth();
};
```

**class2.mm**

```
#include "class2.h"
std::string class2::imageName;

//other stuff
```